# One Page Scroll add Active class depending on scroll position

Tags: smooth-scrolling

Hello I have a one page website which uses smooth scroll in the navigation I have also set up a function which applies the active class when the link is clicked and removes it from the otehr links but is there a way to add the active class to the correct link depending on where you are on the page e.g. if I scroll to energy saving section the main nav adds an active class to energy saving.

Here is my code I am using for the smooth scroll.

```
var smoothScroll = function() {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top - $('.fd_PageHeader').height() - 40
                        }, 1000);
                        $('body').removeClass('navVisible navTransition');
                        return false;

                    }

                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

**DIY solution:**

Register an onScroll listener and for each callback compare the current scroll position to the vertical position of the headings.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){ /* callback here */ });
```

The vertical scroll position may be retrieved using [jQuery.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). The topOffset of the headings ([offset().top](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)) needs to be combined with the current window height: `$(window).height();` prior to comparing.

See a POC version here http://jsfiddle.net/b1bc7wbL/

**Easy solution:**

Use a third party module like http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy